# Highcharts: Drawing non-diagonal lines

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

How do I configure **Highcharts** so that lines are drawn as 90-degree zigzags instead of diagonal lines?

**What I have:**

[image]

**What I need:**

[image]

Comment: please include code in your question

Comment: Use [step](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.area.step) property. See example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/3.1.1/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/line-step/)

Comment: Improved grammar in question